# Query not returning SUM, only giving separate values

Tags: sql

Trying to find the total value of items at the store specified, below, in the year 2021. I figured that this would result in the sum of all values for that store within that year, but I just get a bunch of separate event value numbers.

Here are my tables:

[image]

```
SELECT SUM(Event.EventValue)
FROM Event 
INNER JOIN Site 
ON Event.SiteId = Site.SiteId
WHERE Site.SiteName = ‘Flor Emporium Auckland’ AND year(Event.EventDate) = 2021;
GROUP BY Event.EventValue
```

Comment: Because you `GROUP BY Event.EventValue`

Comment: You should show sample input data, desired output data, and current output. But yes, this is just a simple typo/thinko really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want `sum` of all the `EventValue` that satisfy where clause then you need to remove `group by` clause.

```
SELECT SUM(Event.EventValue)
FROM Event 
INNER JOIN Site 
ON Event.SiteId = Site.SiteId
WHERE Site.SiteName = 'Flor Emporium Auckland' AND year(Event.EventDate) = 2021;
```